# problem connecting with odbc mysql in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

I'm trying another method to connect mysql and vb.net. I didn't have any difficulties connecting mysql and vb.net when using mysql net connector. And I also used the same codes. I just replaced the ones that needed to be replaced with odbc.

```
 Imports System.Data.Odbc



Public Class globalclass
    Private cn As New OdbcConnection("DSN=korosu")

    Dim cmd As Odbc.OdbcCommand

    Public name As String
    Public age As String


    Public Sub New()
        cn.Open()
        cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM test")

    End Sub

    Public Sub adds()

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test(name, age) VALUES('" + name + "','" + age + "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



    End Sub
```

What do I need to do to fix this?
I always get the runtime error and its highlighting the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. And says that the connection has not been properly initialized.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified that cmd uses cn.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to set the connection for the OdbcCommand:

```
cn.Open()
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test(name, age) VALUES('" + name + "','" + age + "')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```